# Windows phone - How to exit on double tap?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm learning to develop windows phone application. I started with a browser based app by following this tutorial - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2011/02/04/back-button-press-when-using-webbrowser-control-in-wp7.aspx. I'm experimenting with http://m.facebook.com I can correctly use back button to go to the previous page and all that stuff but I'm not able to implement exit on double tap of back button.

I have seen many browsers app which exit after double tapping the back button. for example - Flipkart - http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/flipkart/84fc03ea-210d-4e3e-88e0-de502a2434c5

There is no double tab event for back button. How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a global `long` that represents the last time the user pressed the back button.
Every time the back button is pressed, you can make your program subtract the number of elapsed ticks. If it has passed a short amount of ticks, you can make your program exit. If not, set the last tick variable once more.

You can get the current tick that represents the current time with `System.DateTime.Ticks`.

Simple code sample:

```
long LastExitAttemptTick = DateTime.Ticks;

private void BackButtonPressHandler(...)
{
    long thisTick = DateTime.Ticks;

    if (LastExitAttemptTick - thisTick < [specified amount])
        throw new Exception("Exit Exception"); //You can use XNA, but this is a quick and dirty way of exiting
    else
        LastExitAttemptTick = DateTime.Ticks;
}
```

You can use a value of 10,000,000 ticks (1 second). [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says 10,000 ticks per millisecond, so 10,000 * 1000 = 10,000,000.

EDIT: Or as you said, you can also use `DateTime.Now` and use the seconds value instead. Either way works.

Comment: I did it before you said it and did not get a chance to look at here. Thank you for taking time to help me out. You are close. Ticks is larger value. I ended up doing DateTime.Now and calculating the difference in Milliseconds. If it is less than 500, I take it as a double tap. Please update your answer and I will mark it.

Answer (score 0):

well this kind of logic could work for you

make a global variable

```
int Count=0





     protected ovverride void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
            {

            if(Count==0)
             {
             e.Canel=true;
              Count++;
             }
            else if(Count==1)
             {
              Count=0;
              //code for exiting
              //may be App.Current.Terminate(); in wp8
             //or in wp7
             //if (NavigationService.CanGoBack)  
             //{
             //    while (NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry() != null)
             //   {
             //        NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
            //    }
             //}
             }
            }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: e.Cancel=true; should only apply in the if(Count==0)-part.

Answer (score 0):

To close the application on **double click**, you can use `DispatcherTimer` task to check whether a two clicks are within one second, if yes close the application else start `timer` and again check. The snippet for that as follows:

make a `DispatcherTimer` object as a class field like,

```
DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
```

In your `class's constructor` specify the `interval` you want to check for **double tap** and also add `event handler` to perform some action when specified time has elapsed. You can do in a `class's constructor`,

```
dt.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0);
dt.Tick += delegate(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    dt.Stop();
};
```

Here what we're doing is we're specifying `timespan` of 1 second to check whether double tap occurs within that second. Tick event is for what we want to do when timer completes its 1 second. We're simply going to stop the `timer`.

Now navigate to **back key event handler** and here is my code to check double tap:

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    if (!dt.IsEnabled)
        dt.Start();
    else
        new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game().Exit();
}
```

When for the first tap, `timer` is not started, it will go to if condition and will start the timer. If second tap occurs after 1 second, then the `Tick` event we wrote in constructor will fire and according to logic written there, the `timer` will stop.

Now assume the **double tap** occurs consequently within 1 second. For the 1st tap as usual it will start the `timer`, if immediately user presses **back button** again, then in its handler, it will check whether `timer` is running. As `timer` has not completed its 1 second interval, else condition will fired up and the application will close.

I used `XNA library` / shortcut to **force close** the application. To work with `new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game().Exit();` method you should add a **`microsoft.xna.framework.game.dll`** in a reference.

Make **`TimeSpan`** interval as required.

Hope this helps. Thanks.

**`EDIT:`**

Sometimes XNA is not installed on windows 8. Here is a solution for that, so that you add above mentioned assembly reference in you project.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2012/02/29/10274694.aspx

You have to download update which is around around 23MB.

To save time here's a Dropbox link to above assembly reference:

https://db.tt/RYTwv7cS

Comment: Cool.. but I do not want that Library to be added unnecessarily. I did it with an approach similar to Andrew's. See my comment there. But thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is no Double Tap event for back button. You have to write your own logic to exit application on Double Tap on device back key tap twice. Here is the solution this may be help you.

Create a Global variable and initialize with zero

Int TapCount =0;

Now Override OnBackKeyPress event with your own logic.

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
           TapCount++;
         if(TapCount==2)
          {
            if( windows phone 8 )
               {
                 Application.Current.Terminate(); 
               }
              else
              {
                 if (NavigationService.CanGoBack)
                {
                  while (NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry() != null)
                  {
                     NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
                  }
               }
            }

          }
         else
           e.Canel=true;
            base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
        }
```

Comment: What's the meaning of `if( windows phone 8 )`?

Comment: that means if your app running in wp8 environment

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. I've implemented it like this:

First declare global variable:

```
int count;
```

Now initialize its value in **OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)** method:

```
count = 0;
```

Now at last add the below code to your cs file:

`protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            count++;
            e.Cancel = true;
            if(count == 2)
            { e.Cancel = false; base.OnBackKeyPress(e); }
        }`