# User control level back functionality in wp8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, user-controls

In my windows phone app I am trying to use only one page that is `MainPage.xaml` and changing the user control inside it based on user activity. But now I don't know how to implement back functionality with this. It exists the app with one key press but I want it to go to previous control.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: U can try using logic of double back to exit. In this case app is not immediately closed and the user is presented with a messagebox  or toast asking for a confirmtion. What you can try doing is instead of showing the toast, you can go to the previous control. Methodology of doing this is discussed in this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590812/windows-phone-how-to-exit-on-double-tap

Answer (score 1):

To handle back key press, you can use this code:

```
public MainPage()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  this.BackKeyPress += MainPage_BackKeyPress;
}

void MainPage_BackKeyPress(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
     if (...)    // custom check to determine if the user control should be changed ...
     {
          ...    // custom code to change the user control ...
          e.Cancel = true; // Prevent application close
     }        
}
```

The custom code is your responsibility. You can use for example a stack of user controls - pushing old control into the stack when changing the UI, the popping out of the stack when back key is pressed. If the stack is empty, then allow the app to be closed.

Comment: Yes I am handling back press and displaying a prompt before closing the app. And for user control, am trying similar solution like the one you suggested i.e. saving my user controls in a global stack. :)